# appear onclick effect with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on the following page:
http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/bettercss/login-1.html
and would like for the right part of the first sign up box to appear only once "Register with your email address" is clicked on.

I know very little Javascript but I'm guessing that's what I'll need to do that, can somebody point me to a tutorial ?

Cheers

(Edit: The reason I am asking for a link is that I wouldn't know what to look for on Google)

Comment: So you want to hide the inputs, and make the `Register with your...` a button. When this button is clicked the inputs will be visible? Am i correct?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here just to give you a link to a tutorial, that's what google is for. You should attempt this on your own and if you have trouble with *actual code*, then you can/should ask a question here.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: @JNDPNT: why does it have to be done with jQuery? I may be wrong, but I think the OP has more use of a native JS tutorial.

Comment: Use this if user login is not present in page.  $(".bloc-full").toggle(500); Try this with onclick.

Comment: @CharlieAus please post some code that you have tried...

Comment: Since you have jQuery library included, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cf2gA/1/

Comment: @Cerbrus: I doesn't have to be jQuery, but it's easier to get started in this case. Instead of arguing about which platform or native, you could maybe help him out yourself?

Comment: @JNDPNT: done. I don't think it can get a lot easier than that.

Comment: @A.V I'm trying this and that won't work.. (if you don't mind taking a look at it)

Comment: @CharlieAus : It may be because you have older jQuery library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'll add an `id` to these 2 elements:

```
<div class="form-step-1-container" id="myForm"> <!-- <-- ID here -->
    <h1>Register with your email address</h1>
    <div style="display:none;" id="targetDiv"> <!-- <-- ID here -->
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Username" required="required" name="username">
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" required="required" name="email">
        <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Password" required="required" name="password">
        <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Re-Enter your Password" required="required" name="password">
    </div>
</div>
```

With native JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.display = "block";
});
```

This adds a `"click"` event listener to the `"form-step-1-container"` div, that displays the `div` containing the input elements, when clicked.

---

**So, what does this actually do?**

- [`document.getElementById('myForm')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) "Gets" the DOM elements with `id="myForm"`.
- [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) adds an event listener to this object. It's first parameter (`'click'`) specifies what event it should listen ("react") to, it's second parameter is a function to execute when the event happens. This function can be defined in the `addEventListener()`, like I did up here, but you can also define the function elsewhere in the code, and just use the function name in the `addEventListener()`.
- [`.style.display` =](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style) [`"block"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) sets the element's `display` CSS style to the value `"block"`, to display the inputs fields again.

Comment: Thanks you for this complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look like this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-step-1-container">
<h1>Register with your email address</h1>
<div style="display:none;">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Choose a Username" required="required" name="username">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" required="required" name="email">
<input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Password" required="required" name="password">
<input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Re-Enter your Password" required="required" name="password">
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-step-1-container h1').click(function() {
    $('.form-step-1-container div').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: You should mention that this requires to include the external library jQuery.

Comment: @Philipp : The page has loaded jQuery library anyway...

Comment: Instead of using the css, you can also use  $('.form-step-1-container div').show();

Comment: @A.V: Answers on stackoverflow.com should be formulated so that they are helpful for everyone who has the same problem and not just be applicable to the special case of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML element which contains the elements you want to hide into a common HTML element like a `<div>`. Then assign a CSS class to it which includes the style "`display:none`". You can do that in the HTML code, but a better solution would be to assign it with Javascript when the document loads, because in that case the input will be visible for those who have Javascript disabled.

Then add a onclick handler to the the div which replaces the CSS class with one which has `dispay:block`.